# What's the difference between Prolog rules and queries?

Tags: prolog, rules

I'm new to logical programming and find it difficult to understand the difference between rules and queries, I feel they are basically the same. Any help to clarify this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntactically, they are largely the same; "`p(1).`" could be either a rule or a query, depending on where you put it.

Semantically, they are not. 
"`p(1).`" as a rule tells Prolog "`p(1)` is true".
 "`p(1).`" as a query *asks* Prolog "is `p(1)` true?".

Answer (score 2):

A rule is a definition such as

```
foo(X) :- bar(X), baz(X).
```

as it appears in a Prolog program.

A query is either the right hand side of a definition like the above, i.e. `(bar(X), baz(X))` or what you type at the Prolog interpreter prompt to get the program running.

Comment: aren't we querying the same thing in the interpreter? like `foo(X)` ?

Comment: This is the distinction between a consultation (i.e. `[user]`) and the prompt. The query prompt behaves the same way as the body of a predicate. That's why you need to consult a file to add facts and predicates to the database.

Answer (score 0):

A query is a statement you are asking to have proven (which in the process of doing so may instantiate variables, which can server as your "output"); rules make up the "program" used to develop that proof.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct: they're both variations on a Horn clause. The basic structure of a Horn clause is:

```
head(...) :- body.
```

If you have a head without a body, you have a fact. If you have both, you have a predicate. If you have just a body, then you have a query.

Comment: No, if you have both, you have a rule. A predicate definition is a sequence of rules.